# How to splice a tidyselect-style list of column names into a call of my function

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyselect

I am trying to write a function that deduplicates my grouped data frame. It asserts that the values in each groups are all the same and then only keeps the first line of the group. I am trying to give it tidyselect-like semantics like are seen in [`pivot_longer()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html) because I just need to forward the column names into a `summary(a = n_distinct(...))` call.

So for an example table

```r
test <- tribble(
  ~G,  ~F, ~v1, ~v2,
  "A", "a",  1,   2,
  "A", "b",  1,   2, 
  "B", "a",  3,   3,
  "B", "b",  3,   3) %>%
  group_by(G)
```

I expect the call `remove_duplicates(test, c(v1, v2))` (using the tidyselect helper [`c()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/tidyr_tidy_select.html) to return

```
G   F  v1  v2
A   a   1   2
B   a   1   2
```

but I get

```
Error: `arg` must be a symbol
```

I tried to use the new ["embrace"](https://github.com/r-lib/rlang/blob/master/NEWS.md#interpolate-function-inputs-with-the-curly-curly-operator) syntax to solve this (see function code below), which fails with the message shown above.

```r
# Assert that values in each group are identical and keep the first row of each
# group
# tab: A grouped tibble
# vars: <tidy-select> Columns expected to be constant throughout the group
remove_duplicates <- function(tab, vars){
  # Assert identical results for identical models and keep only the first per group.
  tab %>%
    summarise(a = n_distinct({{{vars}}}) == 1, .groups = "drop") %>%
    {stopifnot(all(.$a))}
  # Remove duplicates
  tab <- tab %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    ungroup() 
  return(tab)
}
```

I think that I somehow would need to specify that the evaluation context of the expression `vars` must be changed to the sub-data-frame of `tab` that is currently under evaluation by `substitute`.
So something like

```
tab %>%
  summarise(a = do.call(n_distinct, TIDYSELECT_TO_LIST_OF_VECTORS(vars, context = CURRENT_GROUP))))
```

but I do not understand the technical details enough to really make this work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected if you first `enquos` your `vars` then use the curly-curly operator on the result:

```r
remove_duplicates <- function(tab, vars){
  
  vars <- enquos(vars)

  tab %>%
    summarise(a = n_distinct({{vars}}) == 1, .groups = "drop") %>%
    {stopifnot(all(.$a))}

  tab %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()
}
```

So now

```r
remove_duplicates(test, c(v1, v2))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   G     F        v1    v2
#>   <chr> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     a         1     2
#> 2 B     a         3     3
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! However, I don't understand why there is the new `{{` operator then. Because if I write `!!vars` instead of `{{vars}}` it works as well. What is the benefit of `{{`, then?

Comment: @akraf this seems to be a problem with `n_distinct` rather than the way you are using the curly-curly operator. I don't know if it is perhaps because both `summarise` and `n_distinct` use `enquos` internally?